# Classifying spaces for holomorphic bundles

Tags: reference-request, complex-geometry

I am not very experienced in the topic so the question may be naive.

Is there a way to "homotopically" classify holomorphic G-bundles for a complex Lie group G?

So the first subquestion: is there a classifying space, i.e. a holomorphic G-bundle with a "contractible" total space?

Second subquestion: what is the notion of homotopy here?

My guess is that one needs some fancy homotopy theory like $\mathbb{A}^1$-homotopy theory in the complex setting.

Comment: There are a number of differences between bundles in  topological and holomorphic worlds. For example, holomorphic bundles can have continuous parameters (moduli),  so I don't think that classification  up to homotopy would work in any obvious sense...

Comment: @DonuArapura By the same argument, it seems that algebraic bundles should be "unclassifiable." However, I think that motive homotopy theory does just that by giving us a classifying space of all algebraic bundles with fixed structure group